# Alter existing table name

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I change table name without creating a new one?

I have a table with some records in it, if i change the table name in mapping file (xml) and run `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` Doctrine leaves an old table and generates a new empty table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Doctrine is not smart enough to detect such renaming because it would have a big performance impact. So instead of detecting such changes you have to rename the table manually during the update process.

To automate this process you can use Doctrine migrations for which you can find the documentation here:

[Doctrine Migrations Bundle (Symfony2)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)